# Getting wrong data from LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have some tables that has the following structure:

```
cat(
    cat_id(pk),
    cat_name)

ven(
    ven_id(pk),
    ven_name)

cat_van_rel(
    cat_ven_rel_id,
    cat_id(fk),
    ven_id(fk))
```

Given a `ven_id` passed from a function, I want the rows from `cat` whose `id` matches the `cat_id` in the `cat_van_rel` table which matches the `ven_id` that was passed in.

Here's an example of some data:

```
cat:
    cat_id     cat_name
    1           food
    2           alcohol
    3           water
    4           juice


cat_ven_rel:
    cat_ven_rel - cat_id - ven_id
    1           - 1      - 1
    2           - 3      - 1
    3           - 4      - 1
    4           - 2      - 2
    5           - 1      - 2
    6           - 4      - 2
```

So given a `ven_id` `1`, I should get the following rows:

```
1           food
3           water
4           juice
```

This is my query:

```
List<cat> lst = (from x in objEntity.cat
                 where objEntity.cat_ven_rel.Any(y => y.ven.ven_id==venid)
                 select x).ToList();
```

but it's returning all rows from cat table.

How can I fix this?

I Got IT :

from x in cat_ven_rel

where x.Ven.ven_id == venid

thnx for ur replies
select new {x.cat.cat_name,x.cat.cat_id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use function any here,function any is determines whether a sequence contains any elements.if the sequence contains a element it still return true!
you can try:

```
List<cat> lst = (from x in objEntity.cat
where objEntity.cat_ven_rel.where(y => y.ven.ven_id==venid).select(y => y.cat_id).contains(x.cat_id)
select x).ToList();
```

[the introduce of function any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343630%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Invalid expression term 'where'
giving it in - objEntity.cat_ven_rel.where  <----

Comment: the param of func where should be (y => y.ven_id==venid)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `where x.cat_van_rel.ven_id == venid`

(I need the generated EntityModel class to be exact)

HTH

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<Model11.cat_ven_rel,int,bool>' does not take '1' arguments